# Custom allocator & default member

Tags: c++, allocator

Why isn't [this code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20%3Ccstdlib%3E%5Cn%23include%20%3Clist%3E%5Cn%5Cntemplate%20%3C%20typename%20Type%20%3E%5Cnclass%20Allocator%20%7B%5Cnpublic%3A%5Cn%5Ctusing%20value_type%20%3D%20Type%3B%5Cnpublic%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20template%20%3C%20typename%20Other%20%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20struct%20rebind%20%7B%20using%20other%20%3D%20Allocator%3C%20Other%20%3E%3B%20%7D%3B%5Cnpublic%3A%5Cn%5CtType%20*%20allocate(%20std%3A%3Asize_t%20n%20)%20%7B%20return%20std%3A%3Amalloc(%20n%20)%3B%20%7D%5Cn%5Ctvoid%20deallocate(%20Type%20*%20p%2C%20std%3A%3Asize_t%20)%20throw%20(%20)%20%7B%20std%3A%3Afree(%20p%20)%3B%20%7D%5Cn%7D%3B%5Cn%5Cnint%20main(%20void%20)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctstd%3A%3Alist%3C%20void%20*%2C%20Allocator%3C%20void%20*%20%3E%20%3E%20list%3B%5Cn%5Ctreturn%200%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fclang%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-march%3Dnative%22%7D%5D%7D) compiling ?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>

template < typename Type >
class Allocator {
public:
    using value_type = Type;
public:
    template < typename Other >
    struct rebind { using other = Allocator< Other >; };
public:
    Type * allocate( std::size_t n ) { return std::malloc( n ); }
    void deallocate( Type * p, std::size_t ) throw ( ) { std::free( p ); }
};

int main( void ) {
    std::list< void *, Allocator< void * > > list;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to need pointer, reference, pointer_const & reference_const types. However, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) these members are all optionals. It seems like if the STL weren't using allocator_trait (I'm compiling with -std=c++11 so it should be good).

Any idea ?

[edit] On clang, errors are :

```
user@/tmp > clang++ -std=c++11 test.cc
In file included from test.cc:2:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/list:63:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_list.h:449:40: error: no type named 'pointer' in 'Allocator<void *>'
      typedef typename _Tp_alloc_type::pointer           pointer;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
test.cc:17:46: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::list<void *, Allocator<void *> >' requested here
    std::list< void *, Allocator< void * > > list;
                                             ^
In file included from test.cc:2:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/list:63:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_list.h:450:40: error: no type named 'const_pointer' in 'Allocator<void *>'
      typedef typename _Tp_alloc_type::const_pointer     const_pointer;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_list.h:451:40: error: no type named 'reference' in 'Allocator<void *>'
      typedef typename _Tp_alloc_type::reference         reference;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_list.h:452:40: error: no type named 'const_reference' in 'Allocator<void *>'
      typedef typename _Tp_alloc_type::const_reference   const_reference;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: @Nick I have updated my question with clang output (gcc is failing too)

Comment: Note that the c++11 support for basically all compilers is still experimental/incomplete. Therefore it might simply be an implementation bug (can't look up the relevant parts of the standard right now, so that is just a guess if those members are indeed optional)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Allocator<void>` instead of `Allocator<void*>`?

Comment: A sample custom allocator is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090161/415784

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I don't think (T is the type to alloc)

Comment: Compiles for me with a recent `libc++` and `Boost.Container`. Looks like a gcc bug to me.

Comment: @Nawaz true, however the C++11 introduces allocator_trait, which should provide default value for most of these types

Comment: Well, the very first error message says that it's expecting your `Allocator<void *>` instantiation to provide a `typedef <something> pointer;` (or something equivalent), which your `Allocator` class doesn't seem to include...

Comment: @twalberg I know. The question is why does it expect to gave a  pointer` typedef, since it should not (`std::allocator_trait` should gives default values) ? It seems that the standard containers does not use `std::allocator_trait`, and I would like to know if it's a bug, or if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC's C++ standard library.

When using a list, they are not properly wrapping access to the allocator through an allocator_traits.

However, they do implement vector correctly. This code would compile if you used `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.